# Dynamically arranging QWidgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a GUI application, in which the user will be faced with this dialog:

[image: sample screenshot here]

Here the user will have to type in symbols of publicly traded stocks and then add them to a list.
The elements of the list should be displayed separately inside the `QFrame` (should there be a better option, then that), where they can be easily removed with an X button. The tagging of StackOverflow questions actually looks very similar to what I want:

[image: screenshot of StackOverflow tags here]

I can create the small widgets for the symbols and the X buttons, but how can I achieve that they are arranged in lines?

Some details:

- The symbols are not from a pre-defined list; the user should be able to type in any strings
- The symbol widgets have a fixed size
- A new line should start whenever the symbols reach the right side of the frame
- If there are too much symbols to be displayed in the frame, the frame should turn scrollable

Is there a way to do these tasks in the Qt Designer? If not, then how to do it in Python code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `QPushButton`s as children to `QLineEdit` and adjust its padding accordingly to achieve something similar to tags edit ui.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    tagAdded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._buttons = []
        self._tags = ["qt", "pyqt", "python"]
        self.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self._height = -1

    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        if text not in self._tags:
            return

        if self._height < 0:
            self._height = self.height()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text, self)

        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.removeButton(self._buttons.index(button)))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont(self.font().family(), self.font().pointSize()-2)
        button.setFont(font)
        metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        width = metrics.horizontalAdvance(text) + 10
        height = self._height - 2
        button.setGeometry(0,0,width,height)
        button.show()
        self.setText("")

        self._buttons.append(button)
        self.adjustButtons()

        self.tagAdded.emit(text)

    def adjustButtons(self):
        x = 1
        for button in self._buttons:
            rect = button.geometry()
            rect.moveTopLeft(QtCore.QPoint(x, 0))
            button.setGeometry(rect)
            x += rect.width()
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {padding-left: " + str(x) + "px}")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace and self.text() == "" and len(self._buttons) > 0:
            self.removeButton(len(self._buttons) - 1)
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def removeButton(self, index):
        button = self._buttons.pop(index)
        button.setParent(None)
        button.deleteLater()
        self.adjustButtons()

    def tags(self):
        return [button.text() for button in self._buttons]

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        edit = LineEdit()
        font = QtGui.QFont(edit.font().family(), 14)
        edit.setFont(font)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```